# Characters or substructure?

Tags: worldbuilding-process

My name is Paul and I'm french so excuse me about my bad english (and it's not a reason to read this with the accent !). I'm here because I began to dream and create my own scifi universe but I meet some problems.

For my first post I have just a "simple" question for you all : should I focus more on the development of the characters or on the development of the substructure of the world ?

It's complicated because I involved myself on a big big project (with musics and drawings) and for now I'm alone on this. Therefore I have to do everything step by step but I've got billions ideas come into my head !

Comment: I would say focus on the world because the world can shape characters : characters from an utopia are very different from the ones living in a post-apocalyptic world for example.

Comment: Welcome to the site Sauvage.  You question is interesting and one I assure you we have all thought about.  As it is though the answer to your question is a matter of opinion.  Some writers prefer to go with characters, others to go with setting.  Your use case also matters, some are writing for table top gaming other for novels etc.  This would be a great topic to bring to the chatroom once you get a little more reputation on the site.

Comment: Don't take the question closing personally getting used to the SE format takes a bit of time and we were all there at one point.  SE is a Q/A site first and foremost, not a forum for discussion.  Check out the [tour] and [help] to get a little more background on how the site works.

Comment: Hello Paul and welcome to Worldbuilding! Be sure to visit the [Help Center](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help) to improve your question. For now it is too broad to provide you a good answer. What have you done for now, what to you want to improve? ...

Comment: @Hawker65 okay thank you, i'll keep this in my mind

Comment: @James alright I understand ! The matter is that I'm not a writer or something like that, I just building a scifi world in a wiki form

Comment: @Ckankonmange as I said before to James I creating my world in a wiki form, and the problem is that I've so much ideas to set up but I am a little lost against the wave of works. I called the universe Vulgae if you want to see it go on www.vulgae.com

Comment: I confess, once you mentioned not reading the question with with the accent, I immediately read it with the accent :)  Anyway, I'd start with a really open idea about internal logic.  Hard Sci-Fi, or magical fantasy?  So long as you decide on some sort of internal logic, and stick with it, the rest tends to get easier for me.

Comment: @PaulTIKI Ahah I had warned ! Ok I see, my world is more a sci-fi world than a magical world. But you can do like magic exists if you can explain it scientifically. I think I'll should focus myself on the setting, it's more important maybe than characters

Comment: @P.Sauvage.  Magic or technology, just make it consistent.  Think of how the good stories with un-believable aspects work.  Star Trek, Star Wars, many RPG's all tend to have a consistent system.  When they break that rule, readers check out.

Comment: I believe [writing.se](https://writing.stackexchange.com/) would be a good fit for this question.